# can't figure how to write this out.

Tags: trigonometry

A Funnel used to pour oil into an engine is in the shape of a cone. The sides of the cone are 15cm long and the angle between the sides is 17.9°. What is the diameter of the cone, to the nearest centimeter?

Comment: $$sin(\frac{\theta_{Cone\_Angle}}{2}) = \frac{radius}{\text{Side of Cone}}$$

Comment: Try drawing and labeling the cone

Answer (score 0):

Drawing helps. Note the picture is not to scale. You are trying to find $2R$. Let's find $R$ first.

Draw a line from the base of the cone to its top. This will half the angle at the top because the sides are equal.

Calculate the missing angle. You know a triangle has 180 degrees.

Use the law of sines to get the required lengths:

$$\frac{sin 8.95}{R}=\frac{sin 90}{15}$$

$sin 90$ is $1$, $sin 8.95$ is about $.16$. Be careful with rounding. Your book answer may be slightly different because of the rounding.

From the above $R=2.33$ and you can get $2R$ easily.

[image]